Error while exporting Tensorflow model to CoreML
'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec'
import tensorflow as tf
import coremltools as ct
print(tf.__version__)
# Load your existing Keras model
model_path = "/Users/name/Desktop/model.h5"
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

# Save the model in SavedModel format
model.save(model_path, save_format='tensorflow')

# Convert the SavedModel to CoreML, specifying the source as 'tensorflow'
coreml_model = ct.convert(model_path, source='tensorflow')

# Save the CoreML model
coreml_model.save("/Users/name/Desktop/model.mlmodel")

I was told to downgrade the versions and I did all the way to tensorflow 2.13.0. Any guidance is appreciated.


can you share more information about your model (what layers are there and etc? Can it be downloaded from anywhere?). I have created dummy sequential model and everything compiled successfully for me.

If possible please output model.summary()

sure i've added it please take a look

sry, still doesn't give any clue. Is it possible to upload model.h5 somewhere? You can replace all weights with random values if obfuscation is needed.

Also, did you check this thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/63867 They claim that it is worth trying to use legacy keras as a workaround import os;os.environ["TF_USE_LEGACY_KERAS"]="1"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IBVi1q5u8eSg1EXZ2vmiXknXVXSPuyVe/view?usp=sharing
If you're able to convert to coreML, let me know. Thanks for the help!

here is what worked for me. As far as I understood your 'h5' file was created by keras library and not tf.keras what creates the problem.
import tensorflow as tf
import coremltools as ct
import keras

print(tf.__version__)     # 2.15.0
print(keras.__version__)  # 3.4.1
print(ct.__version__)  # 7.2


# model was saved using keras and not tf.keras (!!)
model_path = "model.h5"
model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)


# convert keras model to tensorflow model
tf_model_path = 'tf_model' # '.pb' model
tf.saved_model.save(model, tf_model_path)


# # Convert the SavedModel to CoreML, specifying the source as 'tensorflow'
coreml_model = ct.convert(tf_model_path, 
                          source='tensorflow',
                          convert_to="mlprogram")


converted_path = 'model.mlpackage'
# # Save the CoreML model
coreml_model.save(converted_path)


This worked, thanks a lot. Didn't know that there's separate ways to save it if it's tf.keras or just keras.

I tried this approach but I'm getting this error TypeError: this __dict__ descriptor does not support '_DictWrapper' objects on the line tf.saved_model.save(model, tf_model_path) even using the same model that was provided.

@OluwatobiOmotayo could you please create a new question, add the code that you are using, version of libraries that you have and the link to the saved weights that you are loading.
