Error converting Tensorflow model to CoreML model
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 1
----> 1 mlmodel = ct.convert(model, convert_to="mlmodel", source="tensorflow")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/_converters_entry.py:551, in convert(model, source, inputs, outputs, classifier_config, minimum_deployment_target, convert_to, compute_precision, skip_model_load, compute_units, package_dir, debug, pass_pipeline)
    539 exact_target = _determine_target(convert_to, minimum_deployment_target)
    540 _validate_conversion_arguments(
    541     model,
    542     exact_source,
   (...)
    549     minimum_deployment_target,
    550 )
--> 551 need_fp16_cast_pass = _need_fp16_cast_pass(compute_precision, exact_target)
    553 if pass_pipeline is None:
    554     pass_pipeline = PassPipeline()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/_converters_entry.py:624, in _need_fp16_cast_pass(compute_precision, convert_to)
    620 def _need_fp16_cast_pass(
    621     compute_precision: Optional[Union[precision, FP16ComputePrecision]], convert_to: Text
    622 ) -> bool:
    623     if convert_to not in ("mlprogram", "neuralnetwork", "milinternal", "milpython"):
--> 624         raise NotImplementedError(f"Backend converter {convert_to} not implemented")
    626     if compute_precision is None:
    627         return convert_to != "neuralnetwork"

NotImplementedError: Backend converter mlmodel not implemented

No idea what this error means. I am trying to convert my CNN model, which I built using tensorflow, to a coreml model, but I keep getting the error above.
mlmodel = ct.convert(model, convert_to="mlmodel", source="tensorflow")

This is done after importing the model from a saved .h5 file.

As the error is saying as an covert_to argument you should use one of the following "mlprogram", "neuralnetwork", "milinternal", "milpython". You need to read about each of this formats and select one that will work for your case.

As the error is saying as an covert_to argument you should use one of the following "mlprogram", "neuralnetwork", "milinternal", "milpython". You need to read about each of this formats and select one that will work for your case.
Here is reference from the manual:
mlprogram - is the Core ML program format. The model saved from this returned object is executable on iOS15, macOS12, watchOS8, and tvOS15.
neuralnetwork - is the original Core ML format. The model saved from this returned object is executable either on iOS13/macOS10.15/watchOS6/tvOS13 and newer, or on iOS14/macOS11/watchOS7/tvOS14 and newer, depending on the layers used in the model.
milinternal - Returns an MIL program object. An MIL program is primarily used for debugging and inspection.
milpython - barely documented somewhere. But comments in the code says that it is one of the internal data structure, thus shouldn't be used by users.

With mlprogram , there’s a problem saying “Sequential model has no attribute get_save_spec”.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78760922/error-while-exporting-tensorflow-model-to-coreml
That’s another question I asked
